# iphone google maps - direction using latitude and longitude

Tags: iphone, google-maps

I'm working on iphone app.
I know my current location (latitude and longitude) and destination's (latitude and longitude).
How can I use "Google maps" to find the directions. URL for google maps is something like "http://maps.google.com/maps?daddr=San+Francisco,+CA&saddr=cupertino"

From above URL, inspite of source and destination places i want to use latitude and longitude. how?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
NSString* url = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=%f,%f&daddr=%f,%f",
                                            currentLocation.coordinate.latitude, currentLocation.coordinate.longitude, 
                                            destLocation.coordinate.latitude, destLocation.coordinate.longitude];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: [NSURL URLWithString: url]];
```

Answer (score 2):

Rob is right.

You can do something like below, just providing the Destination ( or start address )

> http://maps.google.com/maps?daddr=-37.8218956215849,144.9599325656891

Or even

> http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=-37.8218956215849,144.9599325656891&daddr=-37.8218956215849,144.9599325656891

It's just replacing **start** & **end** with the lat/langs.

> http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=start&daddr=end

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just sticking the Latitude and Longitude in as the parameters? In my experience Google APIs are pretty loose on what you can put into them. The Google Local API can take almost anything including lat lng as a query for example.